# Как сделать авторизацию на сайте через аккаунт Wargaming?

Tags: php, html, база-данных, api, авторизация

Как сделать авторизацию на сайте через аккаунт Wargaming?
Как это реализовано на подобных [сайтах](https://wotgold.ru/).

Подскажите, буду благодарен.

Comment: https://developers.wargaming.net/reference/all/wot/auth/login/